# MVC .Net C# How can I make decisions based upon runtime values of an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime

I have the following code, which takes in two objects and returns a list of the properties that may have changed:

```
public static List<ConfirmRow> EnumerateFormDiffs(object dbForm, object webForm)
{
var output = new List<ConfirmRow>();
var type = dbForm.GetType();

PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in propertyInfos)
{
    Type propertyType = property.GetType();
    if (!propertyType.IsPrimitive && !propertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && !propertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
    {
        continue;
    }

    var oldVal = property.GetValue(dbForm, null);
    var newVal = property.GetValue(webForm, null);
    if (oldVal != null && newVal != null)
    {
        if (oldVal.ToString() != newVal.ToString())
        {
            var displayName = (ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(property.Name, new ViewDataDictionary(dbForm)).DisplayName ?? property.Name);
            var tmp = new ConfirmRow
            {
                FieldName = displayName,
                OldValue = DisplayField(property.Name, type.Name, oldVal),
                NewValue = DisplayField(property.Name, type.Name, newVal)
            };
            output.Add(tmp);
        }
    }
    else if (oldVal == null && newVal != null)
    {
        var displayName = (ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(property.Name, new ViewDataDictionary(dbForm)).DisplayName ?? property.Name);
        var tmp = new ConfirmRow { FieldName = displayName, OldValue = "", NewValue = DisplayField(property.Name, type.Name, newVal) };
        output.Add(tmp);
    }
    else if (newVal == null && oldVal != null)
    {
        var displayName = (ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(property.Name, new ViewDataDictionary(dbForm)).DisplayName ?? property.Name);
        var tmp = new ConfirmRow { FieldName = displayName, OldValue = DisplayField(property.Name, type.Name, oldVal), NewValue = "" };
        output.Add(tmp);
    }
}
return output;
}
```

And I am comparing two "Enrollment" objects :

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .

    public SaveSubmitStatus? SaveSubmitStatus { get; set; }

}
```

Where SaveSubmitStatus is an Enum.

Now, I want to tell my code to NOT look at the "Client" field, because that is causing problems, but I DO want it to see when the "SaveSubmitStatus" field has changed.  When I debug this, on both properties the PropertyType is "RuntimePropertyInfo".  Can anyone tell me how to determine, and include in my if statement, to look at the difference on the "SaveSubmitStatus" field?  I cannot find anything in the object when debugging to allow me to determine this.

Comment: Something you can do is writing in a check on the get statement of the Client fields. like `get{ if(SaveSubmitStatus.hasvalue){ //get the field } }`

Comment: For the most part, I'm not concerned with whether SaveSubmitStatus is null or not, I just need to do special actions depending upon whether or not property in my foreach loop is of type Client or SaveSubmitStatus (I'll have other types down the road too).

Answer (score 1):

To check for the nullable, you can try this

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null
```

or for the generic types, you can use similar to the following

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
   //nullable type
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not really concerned about the nullable, nor about the generic types, I don't think, unless I misunderstand.

What I really need to do is check whether I am on the Client or SaveSubmitStatus property in that foreach loop, if you have any idea as to how I could approach that?

Comment: You can check with the following condition `if (property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(StringBuilder)))
{

}
`
To check if it is a class than a value type can be done with the following 
`if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
{
    
}`
Hope this helps you in deciding

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not find an elegant solution, but it will work to allow me to get this functionality out to our client.

With the property variable, and the propertyType variable, I was getting confused.  At runtime, the property variable is still aware of the name of the property (I thought this was being set to a generic "RuntimePropertyInfo" value).  I can just use the name of the property, and this will work for our situation, and will actually generalize properly.

Thanks all for reading/offering help.